# Entity Framework: Tracking changes to independent associations

Tags: entity-framework

Entity framework makes it easy to track changes to relationships between two entities. The following will return ObjectStateEntry instances for all added and deleted relationships:

```
ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted)
                .Where(e => e.IsRelationship);
```

For audit purposes I want to retrieve the following information about each association end:

- navigation property name (if any)
- multiplicity

For added associations ObjectStateEntry instance contains EntityKey objects for both entities involved in the relationship:

```
var key0 = entry.CurrentValues[0] as EntityKey;
var key1 = entry.CurrentValues[1] as EntityKey;
```

It also references the type that represents current relationships:

```
var relationshipType = objectStateEntry.EntitySet.ElementType;
```

What I am trying to do is map each entity key (key0, key1) to the appropriate ends of association (relationshipType.KeyMembers). The only way to do this as far as I can tell is to look at the referenced type of each association end and match it with the type of the entity represented by an entity key. However, this will not work if the both ends of an association reference the same entity type (think employee entity with manager FK that references another employee).

So here are helper functions that I got so far to get navigation property name and multiplicity of a relationship end. Is there a better way to do the same?

```
public static string GetNavigationPropertyName(
        this ObjectStateEntry entry, EntityKey key)
{
    var relationshipType = entry.EntitySet.ElementType;
    var entitySet = key.GetEntitySet(
            entry.ObjectStateManager.MetadataWorkspace);
    var property = entitySet.ElementType.NavigationProperties.Where(
            p => p.RelationshipType == relationshipType)
            .SingleOrDefault();

    if (property == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return property.Name;
}

public static RelationshipMultiplicity GetAssociationEndMultiplicity(
        this ObjectStateEntry entry, EntityKey key)
{
    var relationshipType = entry.EntitySet.ElementType;

    var entitySet = key.GetEntitySet(
            entry.ObjectStateManager.MetadataWorkspace);

    foreach (EdmMember member in relationshipType.KeyMembers)
    {
        var refType = member.TypeUsage.EdmType as RefType;
        if (refType.ElementType == entitySet.ElementType)
        {
            var relEndMember = member as RelationshipEndMember;
            return relEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity;
        }
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "couldn't find association end");
}
```

Any suggestions/ideas are welcome.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of looking at entity keys one should extract association ends from object state entry. I saw a hint in Daniel Simmons' blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2008/01/17/ef-extension-methods-extravaganza-part-ii-relationship-entry-irelatedend.aspx. Here are some extension methods that I came up with (UsableValues is also from Daniel's blog):

```
public static AssociationEndMember[] GetAssociationEnds(
        this ObjectStateEntry entry)
{
    var fieldMetadata = 
            entry.UsableValues().DataRecordInfo.FieldMetadata;

    return fieldMetadata.Select(
            m => m.FieldType as AssociationEndMember).ToArray();
}

public static AssociationEndMember GetOtherAssociationEnd(
        this ObjectStateEntry entry, AssociationEndMember end)
{
    end.ValidateBelongsTo(entry);
    AssociationEndMember[] ends = entry.GetAssociationEnds();
    if (ends[0] == end)
    {
        return ends[1];
    }
    return ends[0];
}

public static EntityKey GetEndEntityKey(
        this ObjectStateEntry entry, AssociationEndMember end)
{
    end.ValidateBelongsTo(entry);

    AssociationEndMember[] ends = entry.GetAssociationEnds();

    if (ends[0] == end)
    {
        return entry.UsableValues()[0] as EntityKey;
    }

    return entry.UsableValues()[1] as EntityKey;
}

public static NavigationProperty GetNavigationProperty(
        this ObjectStateEntry entry, AssociationEndMember end)
{
    end.ValidateBelongsTo(entry);

    var otherEnd = entry.GetOtherAssociationEnd(end);
    var relationshipType = entry.EntitySet.ElementType;
    var key = entry.GetEndEntityKey(end);            
    var entitySet = key.GetEntitySet(
            entry.ObjectStateManager.MetadataWorkspace);
    var property = entitySet.ElementType.NavigationProperties.Where(
            p => p.RelationshipType == relationshipType &&
                    p.FromEndMember == end && p.ToEndMember == otherEnd)
            .SingleOrDefault();
    return property;
}
```

ValidateBelongsTo extension method (UsableValue is another extension method from Daniel's blog):

```
static void ValidateBelongsTo(
        this AssociationEndMember end, ObjectStateEntry entry)
{
    if (!entry.IsRelationship)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("is not a relationship entry", "entry");
    }

    var fieldMetadata =
            entry.UsableValues().DataRecordInfo.FieldMetadata;
    if (fieldMetadata[0].FieldType as AssociationEndMember != end &&
        fieldMetadata[1].FieldType as AssociationEndMember != end)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(
                "association end {0} does not participate in the " +
                "relationship {1}", end, entry));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to find the ValidateBelongsTo method. Could you please help.

Comment: I updated the post with ValidateBelongsTo. Its a sanity check, doesn't do any work though.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer did not work for me, and it's probably because I'm using inheritance.  The following modification to LeffeBrune's answer solved this problem for me in Entity Framework 6.1:

```
public static NavigationProperty GetNavigationProperty(this ObjectStateEntry entry, AssociationEndMember end)
{
    end.ValidateBelongsTo(entry);

    var otherEnd = entry.GetOtherAssociationEnd(end);
    var relationshipType = entry.EntitySet.ElementType;
    var entitySet = end.GetEntityType();
    var property = entitySet.NavigationProperties
                            .SingleOrDefault(p => p.RelationshipType == relationshipType &&
                                                  p.FromEndMember == end &&
                                                  p.ToEndMember == otherEnd);
    return property;
}
```

The problem with the original is that the EntitySet retrieved from the key is the EntitySet of the base class, which means that the set of NavigationProperties does not include any properties from the subclass(es).

There were other things I needed as well, so since it took me a really long time to get all of this to work, I'm posting the rest here for posterity:

```
internal void GetPropertyNames(ObjectContext ctx, ObjectStateEntry entry,
                                out string fromPropName, out string toPropName,
                                out object sourceEntity, out object destEntity)
{
    var valueCollection = entry.UsableValues();

    EntityKey entityKeyFrom = (EntityKey) valueCollection[1];
    EntityKey entityKeyTo = (EntityKey) valueCollection[0];

    ObjectStateEntry sourceEntry = ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entityKeyFrom);
    ObjectStateEntry destEntry = ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entityKeyTo);
    sourceEntity = sourceEntry.Entity;
    destEntity = destEntry.Entity;

    Debug.Assert(sourceEntity != null || destEntity != null, "Wait, what?  One of these MUST exist.");

    AssociationEndMember[] ends = entry.GetAssociationEnds();

    Debug.Assert(ends.Length == 2);

    NavigationProperty sourceProp = entry.GetNavigationProperty(ends[1]);
    NavigationProperty destProp = entry.GetNavigationProperty(ends[0]);

    fromPropName = sourceProp.Name;
    toPropName = destProp.Name;

    if (fromPropName == null && toPropName == null)
    {
        AssociationSet assoc = (AssociationSet)entry.EntitySet;
        AssociationType assocType = (AssociationType)assoc.ElementType;

        throw new Exception(String.Format("Couldn't find at least one property for relationship \"{0}\"", assocType.Name));
    }
}
```